# How should the time complexity be calculated of the following recursive code:

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, time-complexity

Should the the time complexity be calculated as T(n-1,m-1)/T(n-1,m or T(n-2)?

```
def isDeelRijRecursief(lijst1,lijst2):
    if len(lijst1) == 1: #vergelijking , hieruit constante halen
        if len(lijst2) > 1: 
            return False

    if len(lijst2) == 1: #vergelijking
        for i in range(len(lijst1)):
            if lijst2[0] == lijst1[i]:
                return True
        return False

    else:
        if lijst1[0] == lijst2[0]: #vergelijking
            return isDeelRijRecursief(lijst1[1:],lijst2[1:]) #T(n-1,m-1)? or T(n-2)?   
        else:
            return isDeelRijRecursief(lijst1[1:],lijst2) # of T(n-1,m)? or T(n-1)?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time complexity is usually defined in [big-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) notation to signify the asymptotic complexity of the evaluated function, that is, its complexity in the limit.

Let's say that the sizes of the first and second lists are N and M respectively. The recursive step of your function always creates a new sublist of size N-1. This means that the recursion will bottom-out after at most N steps. The termination condition of the function must also perform at most N operations. This means that time complexity of the function is in fact `O(N)`, that is, the number of operations that this algorithm will perform is **on the order of N** or that it is **asymptotically linear** in the size of its first argument.